# C# - Transferring foreign key relationships to new ID

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Suppose I have a DB table called "AB" that contains 2 int columns that form a primary key: A and B. It currently contains these 2 rows (in real life it would have many more rows):

### (A, B)

(1, 1),
(1, 2),
(2, 1),
(3, 2)

Using EntityFramework, I want to "merge" the rows that contain a B value of 2 into the rows that contain a B value of 1. All of the rows that contained a B value of 2 should be transferred after the merge operation. I want the result to look like this:

### (A, B)

(1, 1),
(2, 1),
(3, 1)

How would I go about accomplishing this using EntityFramework? So far, I have thought of doing this (pseudocode):

```
foreach (ABRow in entities.AB.Where(ab => ab.B == 2)
{
    if (!entities.AB.Any(ab => ab.A == ABRow.A && ab.B == 1)
    {
        ABRow.B = 1; // Modify row to point to ID 1 instead of 2.
    }
    else
    {
        entities.Remove(ABRow); // Delete since it would cause a duplicate row to be created in the DB.
    }
}
```

It seems like this would inefficient though because you would be performing several SQL queries in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get what you want but i have some advice for you:

1.you can use constraints in Sql for the primary key if that what your asking.

2.don't forget to use entities.AB.Savechanges() after every edit in the entity.

Comment: I know it's confusing. I was trying to think of an easier way to explain it. Basically, I want to merge rows that contain duplicate A values and then delete all rows that contain a B value of 2. In other words, the B ID of 2 is really ID 1 and needs to be merged together with any rows that contain ID 1. I feel like that was more confusing than my original explanation...

Comment: That was really harder to understand, I think you should put a simple example about how you need to merge and delete rows

Comment: Another way to say it is I want to do a "union" of the rows where one part of the primary key contains duplicate values. I'll think of a better example and edit the original post.